# How to fix "LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to find interface & endpoints of device , Unable to open raw device 0"?

Tags: usb, connection, phone, mtp, unknown-device

This is a question which seems to have been asked many times - mostly between 5 and ten years ago. I still have had this intermittently (as do others I see with a variety of phones, computers and ubuntu versions) trying to connect my Nokia 3.4 to my Dell based Ubuntu 22.04.  Usually a disconnect/reconnect of the cable makes it work.  However, there was one period last September when I could not get it to work at all.  I simply gave up for a few weeks until it suddenly started working again - Yippee! - Until this week, when it has failed again.  I strongly suspect there is some update somewhere which is causing this on/off behaviour.

I've tried different USB ports and cables. Running gmtp makes no difference - it says 'No device attached' - despite my phone showing up in my file manager etc AND gmtp (wrongly) recognising it as a Nexus/Pixel as below!

I have obviously looked at many other threads and sources to try and sort this out and I see that the most often responses are for the outputs of lsusb and mtp-detect to be posted so, here are mine:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 038: ID 18d1:4ee2 Google Inc. Nexus/Pixel Device (MTP + debug)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:8187 Dell Computer Corp. DW375 Bluetooth Module
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ mtp-detect
libmtp version: 1.1.19

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee2) is a Google Inc Nexus/Pixel (MTP+ADB).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Google Inc: Nexus/Pixel (MTP+ADB) (18d1:4ee2) @ bus 1, dev 12
Attempting to connect device(s)
LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to find interface & endpoints of device
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

Interesting that my device is listed as a Nexus/Pixel - which it is not!

It would be really nice to get a definitive, permanent 'fix' for this ongoing problem.

TIA

Chris

Answer (score 0):

`mtp`, `lsusb`... use the PCIID to identify the connected devices, in your case `VID=18d1 , PID=4ee2` is known as  [Nexus/Pixel Device (MTP + debug)](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/18D1/device/4EE2)

To update the PCIID database list use: `sudo update-pciids`.

Other way to mount your device:

install `jmtpfs`:

```
sudo apt install jmtpfs
mkdir devicemnt
sudo chown $USER:$USER devicemnt
jmtpfs -o allow_other devicemnt/
ls devicemnt
```

To unmount: `fusermount -u devicemnt`

Comment: Thanks for the response. running mtp prompted me to install ferret-vis - which I did. lsusb then ran as before but updating the pciids achieved still the same error as before.  Using the second scenario, all went well until I got:  $ jmtpfs devicement/
Device 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee2) is a Google Inc Nexus/Pixel (MTP+ADB).
LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to find interface & endpoints of device
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MtpErrorCantOpenDevice'
  what():  Can't open device
Aborted (core dumped)  - so I'm still stuck.  thanks again anyway.

Comment: @chrisnd2 Could you report bug to [libmtp on Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libmtp).  Please link this question. Maybe someone will provide the right answer.

Comment: Bug reported @GAD3R  I see a lot of similar reports there so maybe something will get sorted this time! :-)